# Angular 5 rxjs 5.5.2 - import of interval error - "Cannot read property 'call' of undefined"

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm getting the error "Cannot read property 'call' of undefined" when trying to import "Interval"

My imports are:

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';   
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';   
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';   
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';   
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';   
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';   
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';   
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';   
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
```

If I remove the  last import it works fine.

I have this error in the console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
>       at **webpack_require** (inline.bundle.js:55)
>       at eval (home.component.ts:12)
>       at Object.../../../../../src/app/home/home.component.ts (main.bundle.js:134)
>       at **webpack_require** (inline.bundle.js:55)
>       at eval (app.module.ts:23)
>       at Object.../../../../../src/app/app.module.ts (main.bundle.js:52)
>       at **webpack_require** (inline.bundle.js:55)
>       at eval (main.ts:4)
>       at Object.../../../../../src/main.ts (main.bundle.js:394)
>       at **webpack_require** (inline.bundle.js:55)
>   **webpack_require** @ inline.bundle.js:55 (anonymous) @ home.component.ts:12 ../../../../../src/app/home/home.component.ts @
>   main.bundle.js:134
>   **webpack_require** @ inline.bundle.js:55 (anonymous) @ app.module.ts:23 ../../../../../src/app/app.module.ts @
>   main.bundle.js:52
>   **webpack_require** @ inline.bundle.js:55 (anonymous) @ main.ts:4 ../../../../../src/main.ts @ main.bundle.js:394
>   **webpack_require** @ inline.bundle.js:55 0 @ main.bundle.js:409
>   **webpack_require** @ inline.bundle.js:55 webpackJsonpCallback @ inline.bundle.js:26 (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:1

**UPDATE**
I think perhaps the problem is with using interval? I tried using timer as follows and it worked.

```js
import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer';  

var numbers = timer(5000);
numbers.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

but this produces "Cannot read property 'call' of undefined"

```js
import { interval } from 'rxjs/observable/interval';

var numbers = interval(1000);
numbers.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipeable operators are the new and preferred way of importing and using rxjs operators. For further information, have a look at the [rxjs docs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md).

```js
import { map, filter, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';
source$.pipe(
  filter(x => x % 2 === 0),
  map(x => x + x),
  scan((acc, x) => acc + x, 0)
)
```

Other operators (e. g. creating Observables) can be imported and used directly:

```js
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/observable/combineLatest';

combineLatest(this.first$, this.second$, (first, second) => ({first, second}))
```

Comment: Can you share a code snippet using interval?  I tried to  import { interval } from 'rxjs/observable/interval'; and then let tick = interval(1000) and I get "cannot read property call of undefined"

Comment: I've created a stackblitz that shows it works just like that. Something else must be wrong.
https://angular-lpmrtd.stackblitz.io

Comment: Maybe try to update your dependencies with `npm update` and `npm outdated` to see possible major updates, might be a bug in some of your libraries.